# Trying to make a Seek and Flee behavior. Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2'

Tags: c#, xna, artificial-intelligence, behavior, seek

I'm trying to make a Seek and Flee behavior for an AI project. I tried putting the algorithm but I get this error. I'm not getting why it is not working and I could use some guidance.

Here is the segment of code that isn't working:

```
public Vector2 Seek(Vector2 source, Vector2 target, float maxAccel)
{
     Vector2 acceleration = (target - source).Normalize() * maxAccel;
     return acceleration;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `Normalize()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198260.aspx) says it returns a void, but you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `Vector2`. You'll probably want to use [this variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198252.aspx) of the `Normalize()` function as follows:

```
Vector2 acceleration = Vector2.Normalize(target - source) * maxAccel;
```

I assume that both `target` and `source` are of type `Vector2` and `maxAccel` is a scalar value.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the algorithm.